# Setting connection parameters postgresql in ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, pg

When I run my `rails server`, and load up my `localhost:3000` page, I get an error saying that I haven't supplied the database password.

I'm using the better errors gem, so it shows me to go to my `postgresql-adapter.rb` file (located at `C:\RailsInstaller\Ruby1.9.3\lib\ruby\gems\1.9.1\gems\activerecord-4.0.0\lib\active_record\connection_adapters`) and go to line 825. The code block around that line is this:

# Connects to a PostgreSQL server and sets up the adapter depending on the
        # connected server's characteristics.
        `def connect
          @connection = PGconn.connect(@connection_parameters)`

EDIT:

Here is the contents of my `database.yml` file:

```
<# PostgreSQL. Versions 8.2 and up are supported.
#
# Install the pg driver:
#   gem install pg
# On OS X with Homebrew:
#   gem install pg -- --with-pg-config=/usr/local/bin/pg_config
# On OS X with MacPorts:
#   gem install pg -- --with-pg-config=/opt/local/lib/postgresql84/bin/pg_config
# On Windows:
#   gem install pg
#       Choose the win32 build.
#       Install PostgreSQL and put its /bin directory on your path.
#
# Configure Using Gemfile
# gem 'pg'
#
development:
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  database: frodo-traveller_development
  pool: 5
  username: frodo-traveller
  password:

  # Connect on a TCP socket. Omitted by default since the client uses a
  # domain socket that doesn't need configuration. Windows does not have
  # domain sockets, so uncomment these lines.
  #host: localhost

  # The TCP port the server listens on. Defaults to 5432.
  # If your server runs on a different port number, change accordingly.
  #port: 5432

  # Schema search path. The server defaults to $user,public
  #schema_search_path: myapp,sharedapp,public

  # Minimum log levels, in increasing order:
  #   debug5, debug4, debug3, debug2, debug1,
  #   log, notice, warning, error, fatal, and panic
  # Defaults to warning.
  #min_messages: notice

# Warning: The database defined as "test" will be erased and
# re-generated from your development database when you run "rake".
# Do not set this db to the same as development or production.
test:
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  database: frodo-traveller_test
  pool: 5
  username: frodo-traveller
  password:

production:
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  database: frodo-traveller_production
  pool: 5
  username: frodo-traveller
  password
</code
```

>

Comment: please post your database.yml file

Comment: can you login with just `psql -u frodo-traveller` in the terminal?

Comment: In production there is no ":" after password... Also, I think, If you did'n set up password at all, just remove password line

Comment: I did setup my password, but I don't know what my username or any other parameters should be. When I was setting it up, it said something like "superuser" database, but I'm not sure what that means.

Comment: It says that psql is not recognized ...

Comment: 9/10 you should remove username and password from development. Postgres creates default account for user.

Comment: Do you mean to just remove "username: and password:" lines? Because I did this and the error is still there?

Comment: That yml file just looks all wrong. Blank passwords, missing colons, less than sign at the top before the hash...